# customClaims set from a function doesn't reflect on the front end

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I installed the extension `firestore-stripe-payments` in Firebase. Everything seems to work fine except for one thing, when the user subscribes to a plan or when the subscription ends, the custom claims (`stripeRole` in that case) doesn't reflect on the front end.

After a little investigation I came up with this solution

```js
onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (user) => {
    if (!user) {
        return;
    }

    await user.getIdToken(true); // this forces the token to refresh

    const jwt = await user.getIdTokenResult();

    store.user.isPremium = jwt.claim.stripeRole == 'premium';
});
```

which for me is not really a solution because I believe forcing the token to refresh has some cost (I imagine it can have a small impact on the bill when the number of authenticated users grow), and the word "force" here makes me think it should only be used occasionally.

Is there a recommended way to force the token to refresh from the function directly? how do experienced developers deal with that case?

---

note: For the checkout session, one solution could be to use `${window.location.origin}#checkout_success` for the `success_url` so the front end can use this hint to force the token to refresh. That's one way, but in the case where the user get a one-time payment refunded or just cancel their subscription from a portal, there is no direct way to tell the front-end about that update, or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I believe forcing the token to refresh has some cost (I imagine it can have a small impact on the bill when the number of authenticated users grow)

This is not true.  There is, in fact, no billing at all for Firebase Authentication (except for phone authentication), which is the only product being manipulated with the code you've shown.  It costs nothing to refresh a token.

> Is there a recommended way to force the token to refresh from the function directly?

No, you have to refresh from the client, since the client has to provide the token with every request to Firebase backends.  There is no way to directly "push" anything related to Auth to the client.  At best, you can send some message to client to tell it to refresh the token when needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't understand this part `"which is the only product being manipulated with the code you've shown"`, you confirm that the code I provided has no cost at all, and it's ok to force refresh the token every time `onAuthStateChanged`  is called (regardless of how much the page is reloaded also)?

Comment: Anyways thanks. I had to ask because the pricing page has a checkmark under "Other Authentication services" so I guess it means "we have you covered" but some items on the same page has a "No-cost" mention. So it was a bit confusing.

Comment: As I said in my answer, the only cost is with use of phone authentication. If there was a cost to anything else, it would be clearly noted what the cost per operation would be.